# How to verify the result of sending an e-mail?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I send messages with [The Mail Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/). Is there any way to verify that:

1. message was delivered;
2. message was read?

(I am referring to functions in MS Outlook)

Comment: I think that this answers your question pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875469/how-can-i-know-if-my-email-is-received-and-read-using-asp-net

Comment: @RobinOrheden, thanks. But how can I add header to `mail.send_mail`?

Comment: @RobinOrheden, i.e. I am allowed to add headers - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields, but their list is limited - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview#Sending_Mail_with_Headers

Answer (score 1):

The GAE Python Mail API will not give any information about mail delivery. This issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1800 has been around now for a couple of years and has not been resolved.

As an alternative you can use the Amazon SES web service in GAE. This works great!