# how to know the different status of sended email in c#

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am Creating an application in c# . I have to know how can I know the status of the sended email.The status May be.

```
4. Track sent emails to determine if they were:
4.1 delivered
4.2 opened
4.3 recipient opt-out
4.4 bounced (with the reason for the bounce)
4.5 time/date sent
4.6 which links in the email were clicked (and time/date they were clicked)
4.7 IP address, if user clicked any links in the email
```

Should I use Any API or Dll or something else.Please help .Any Help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you program your application to send mail through a hosted SMTP server like http://www.sendgrid.com or http://www.ultrasmtp.com, you can access the delivery status of messages that you've sent.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do what you want. Actually this status can be tracked by your SMTP server itself and if you are using some third-party SMTP server like GMail or any corporate server, I 'm afraid they won't give you access to those information without using a authenticated client.

From your C# program, if the `SmtpClient.Send()` method returns true, you can assume the mail has been delivered to the SMTP server. If in case, the delivary fails, you should receive a mail to the outbound mail ID's inbox. If you want to make outbound mails appear in your outbox, you should configure IMAP/POP3 configurations accordingly.

There is no API or DLL available in exact form you want, as far as I know. You can try some other way like tracking a hash or embedded image in the mail-body from your server. But these are not reliable way as most mordern Messaging services have counter-measures for this.